# Keeping div always at the middle bottom of the screen with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to keep a div at the bottom of the screen always. And as the div width is smaller than the screen so it should be at the middle of the screen. The First thing is working but it if floating left always.

The code is

```
    <div id="catfish" style="position:fixed; bottom:0;  z-index:5000; width: 468px; margin: 0px auto;">
        <div style="position:absolute;  margin-bottom:0px; z-index:15;">
            <a href="Javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('catfish').style.display='none'"><img src="http://secretdiarybd.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/close.gif.png" alt="close" height="20"></img></a>
        </div>
        <div>
           Some elemnt here
        </div>
    </div>
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/r0esg0fe/)
Please help me.

Comment: Inline CSS/JS is generally considered to be best avoided, btw. It makes things difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add `left` and `right` to your div with value 0.
If you also want the your text in the middle you have to add `text-align: center;`

```
  <div id="catfish" style="position:fixed; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; text-align:center;  z-index:5000; width: 468px; margin: 0px auto;">
        <div style="position:absolute;  margin-bottom:0px; z-index:15;">
            <a href="Javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('catfish').style.display='none'"><img src="http://secretdiarybd.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/close.gif.png" alt="close" height="20"></img></a>
        </div>
        <div>
           Some elemnt here
    </div
    </div>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Add a `margin-left` with the half of the width. Now you can move the container 50% from left. Here you can find a working example:

```css
#catfish {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:5000; 
  background-color:#f00;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-234px; /* Half of the width */
  width: 468px;
}
```

```html
<div id="catfish">
  <div style="position:absolute;  margin-bottom:0px; z-index:15;">
    <a href="Javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('catfish').style.display='none'">
      <img src="http://secretdiarybd.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/close.gif.png" alt="close" height="20"/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>Some elemnt here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div id="catfish" style="position:fixed; bottom:0;  z-index:5000; margin: 0px auto;left: 50%;   transform: translateX(-50%);    padding-left: 30px;">
    <div style="position:absolute;  margin-bottom:0px; z-index:15;left: 0;">
        <a href="Javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('catfish').style.display='none'"><img src="http://secretdiarybd.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/close.gif.png" alt="close" height="20"></img></a>
    </div>
    <div>
       Some elemnt here
</div
</div>
```